# SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000 in @Query - JPA, MySQL, Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA Query for MySQL database. I am passing String date in

> http://localhost:8081/stat/visits/2020-07-29

as `PathVariable` - but getting an error in JPA Repository in Query:
I am using Java8 `LocalDateTime` and for parameter `LocalDate`. Something is wrong with binding. Here are my classes and bellow the error:

Controller

```java
    @GetMapping("/visits/{dateParam}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<WebsiteDailyTotal>> getDailyTotalUsage(@PathVariable("dateParam") String dateParam) {

        LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(dateParam.subSequence(0,dateParam.length()));
        LOGGER.info("ld: {}", ld.toString());

        List<WebsiteDailyTotal> websiteTotalUsage = service.getDomainTotal2(ld);
        return  new ResponseEntity<List<WebsiteDailyTotal>>(websiteTotalUsage, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

JPA Repository:

```java
        public interface TotalDomainRepository2 extends JpaRepository<SuperStatEntityTime, Long> {
        @Query("SELECT new com.proctorio.webtracker.entity.WebsiteDailyTotal(c.domain, SUM(c.duration)) FROM SuperStatEntityTime AS c WHERE c.start.toLocalDate() = :localDate GROUP BY c.domain ORDER BY c.domain ASC")
        public List<WebsiteDailyTotal> countTotalDomainUsageByDay2(@Param("localDate") LocalDate localDate);
    }
```

Entity class:

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "super_stat2")
    public class SuperStatEntityTime {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
    
        @Column
        private String uuid;
    
        @Column
        private String domain;
    
        @Column(name = "start", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
        private LocalDateTime start;
    
        @Column(name = "end", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
        private LocalDateTime end;
    
        @Column
        private Long duration;
```

Database table:

```sql
  CREATE TABLE `super_stat2` (
      `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `domain` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `start` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `end` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `duration` bigint DEFAULT '0',
      `uuid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )
```

The Result class:

```java
public class WebsiteDailyTotal {
    
    private String domainUrl;
    private Long totalTime;
    
    public WebsiteDailyTotal() {
    }
    
    public WebsiteDailyTotal(String domainUrl, Long totalTime) {
        this.domainUrl = domainUrl;
        this.totalTime = totalTime;
    }
```

There is an error:

```
    Hibernate: 
        select
            superstate0_.domain as col_0_0_,
            sum(superstate0_.duration) as col_1_0_ 
        from
            super_stat2 superstate0_ 
        where
            c.start.toLocalDate()=? 
        group by
            superstate0_.domain 
        order by
            superstate0_.domain ASC
    
    
     o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [DATE] - [2020-07-29]
    o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
```

It is syntax error. The query is successful without where clause. Please, help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `toLocalDate()` directly in JPQL. An easier way to fix this calculate start of day and end of day of `localdate` and do between query using them.

```
LocalDateTime startOfDay = localDate.atTime(LocalTime.MIN);
LocalDateTime endOfDay = localDate.atTime(LocalTime.MAX);
```

and query like `c.start between BETWEEN :startOfDay AND :endOfDay`

```
@Query("SELECT new com.proctorio.webtracker.entity.WebsiteDailyTotal(c.domain, SUM(c.duration)) " 
       +"FROM SuperStatEntityTime AS c WHERE c.start between BETWEEN :startOfDay AND :endOfDay GROUP BY c.domain ORDER BY c.domain ASC")
public List<WebsiteDailyTotal> countTotalDomainUsageByDay2(@Param("startOfDay") LocalDateTime startOfDay,
                                                           @Param("endOfDay") LocalDateTime endOfDay);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I am dealing with Java and dbase dates from many years ago,  and have various solutions for all Java date types. It is more of a practice, haven't deal with dates recently - so, with Local Java8 datetime there are even more options. I will add more methods to my old UtilJavaDate class . Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, it's working. Thanks again. And sorry for not being prompt.